# C++ Boost thread sleep deadlock

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, fork

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

void f1(uint count)
{
  while(count-- > 0)
  {
//    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(1000));
    sleep(1);
  }
}

void folkflore()
{
  int res = fork();
  //parent
  if ( res )
   {
     wait(NULL);
   }
  else
   {
     unsigned int x = 2;
     boost::thread tx(boost::bind(f1, 2));
     tx.join();
     _exit(-5);
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Main program " << getpid() << std::endl;
   unsigned int x = 2;
   boost::thread t1(boost::bind(f1, 2));

   boost::thread m(folkflore);
   m.join();
   t1.join();
   return 0;
}
```

[LATER EDIT]
Ok, so it looks like boost::this_thread::sleep acquires a mutex in the behind-scenes, so I guess I'll stick with plain old sleep() which is plain old good for me.
[/LATER EDIT]

From main() I issue a t1 thread which counts 2 seconds and another thread which does the following: fork()'s inside it, the parent waits for the child and the child creates another thread which also counts 2 seconds.

The problem is that if I use boost::this_thread:sleep the program hangs or deadlocks somehow. If I use sleep(), then it works ok. Am I doing something wrong here? What is the difference between these two ?

From the man-page of sleep I get that:

"sleep() makes the calling thread sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored.
"

Also from the boost docs, boost::this_thread::sleep seems to do the same thing.

Comment: Is this your real code? I tested it a lot of times without problems

Comment: Sorry, I reproduced, let's see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do dangerous things here:
fork call duplicates the whole program, but only one thread (current one) running
in new process. So all mutex here, but only one thread.
And if some thread lock mutexes and your thread try lock it in new process,
it will wait forever.

Here

```
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(1000));
```

if look at boost's include file, sleep looks like:

```
this_thread::sleep(get_system_time()+rel_time);
```

get_system_time call tz_convert from libc, which take mutex. And looks like before fork another thread lock it, and...

Comment: I know that fork() duplicates the stack of the current thread. fork() is being called only from the folkflore() function, and from the child I issue another thread, so the child should only have 1 thread. Also, I don't know the inner implementation of boost::this_thread::sleep but I assume it is thread-safe, mutex or not. So the question remains why does this work with sleep() and not with boost::this_thread::sleep ?

Comment: fork not only duplicate stack, it duplicate all memory of process. Read for example http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2003-09/0672.html. Imagine you have two threads, one (1) lock mutex and another(2) try lock it. Lets (1) lock mutex and then disappear, (2) will sleep forever, because of nobody unlock it.

Comment: Ok, I understand your scenario but I think you don't understand my problem. I don't have any mutex here. Maybe boost::this_thread::sleep locks but I assumed it is thread-safe (i.e. locality safe). Also, why does this work with sleep()?

Comment: You have no, but tz_convert has. boost sleep call get_system_time, it calls tz_convert, tz_convert locks its internal global mutex. Then you fork, and create thread where call boot sleep which call get_system_time, which call tz_convert. BUT!!! after fork (if it happened during tz_convert) you have locked internal mutex of tz_convert, but have no thread that unlock it, so you hang.

Comment: And actualy, because of all this stuff is thread safe, you have such problems. If tz_convert has no lock stuff in it, you can not get such problem in your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Then I think that the boost method is implemented wrong. (This is such a corner-case). The implementation details and cave-ats should be specified in the boost docs. Guess I will stick with plain old sleep.